# My scratch project isn't taking key input

Tags: onkeypress, mit-scratch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UYn7.png)

Here is the link : https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/859974239/editor

I have made a scratch project where i have used a if "x" key pressed ,the broadcast "fightmodeon"
and hide , although when i try to do so it doesn't respond to at all

Comment: With scratch, it's difficult to actually help you; but taking a gander at your screenshot, the condition seemed to read ```if x is pressed, it broadcasts "fightmodefordesert" and hide```.  I'm not a scratch programmer, fwiw.

Comment: Yea that's what it's supposed to read although it doesn't seem to work properly ,anyways thanks for your time

Comment: Did you want to broadcast "fightmodeon" or "fightmodefordesert"?

Comment: Sorry for the misconception it is "fightmodefordesert"

Comment: NVM i didnt use forever block,thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to put a forever-loop around the if-statement because otherwise it will check once hen the script starts, now it should chek the entire time and it will hopefully work